# Add test class in changeset?

Tags: unit-test, change-set, migration

Is it necessary to add the **test class** of an apex class in changeset during migration from QA  to PROD?

Suppose apex class is **ABC_apexclass**. Test class for the same is **ABC_apexclass_TEST**. Is it mandatory to add ABC_apexclass_TEST in changeset?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's mandatory to add the test class, however, if you want the code to be covered you will need to include it in Production.

Comment: Do you mean if I want to validate/deploy in PROD, I must have the test classes  present in changeset?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't run tests when deploying between sandboxes nor enforce code coverage. But in order for the class to have it's code covered in production the test class would need to be present. After every deployment it will run all tests to ensure overall coverage. That number (overall, not per class) can't be below 75%. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_code_coverage_best_pract.htm

Comment: So you "technically" do not need it if the overall coverage is above 75% (including the new class) but it is obviously best practice to deploy it if you have it.

Comment: I have been deploying it for a long time, wasn't sure if it needed to be included. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tests classes aren't necessary for change sets. However, you have achieve 75% overall code coverage and min. 1% code coverage for triggers (in prod).

It is important that you achieve 75% at any given time. Otherwise your deployment will fail.